# Magento : How to apply Percentage in Final Price with Custom options?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

We can easily create custom options and add price on product price accordingly custom options.

now, i have one challenge how we can apply percentage price on final price.. default magento can apply on product price (base price).

here, Product price = 10, i have created 2 custom options Test and Other.

While we are select Other Option with Value one it will apply on Product price + Test custom options Price (if selected)

[image]

If any one know than please let us know

Comment: Did you find any solutions on this?